# In php objects, why the static variables can only be accessed with :: notation but the static methods can be called from both :: & ->

Tags: php, function, oop, static

In PHP, for e.g. you define a variable & method static in a class. For its objects, why we can only access variables with :: notation while we can run static methods with -> or :: both? Why this dual behaviour?

```
class first {
    //variable
    public static $var=5;

    //method
    static function new(){
        echo "<br>";
        echo self::$var;
        echo "<br>";
    }
}

class second {

}

$obj = new first();

echo $obj->$var; // this throws an error
echo $obj::$var; // this runs
$obj->new(); // this also runs
$obj::new(); // this runs
```

Comment: I am wondering If there anything wrong with the question? There are down votes to the question.

Comment: As it's written, it sounds opinion based. And can't be answered other than "that's how it was designed". If you would elaborate on your confusion, someone could explain that PHP is not a compiled language.

Comment: @mario so you mean to say that it is how oop is designed or is it just the php ?? and  what is the point in compiled or interpreted languages?

Answer (score 0):

Although arbitrary, a static class variable only belongs to a class, not to an object.
A static class method belongs to both a class and an object of that class.

As demonstrated below, changing a static variable of a class would change the variable in all instances of that class. So the -> notation would be deceitful. This does not happen with a static class method.

Imagine that -> would be allowed on static variables, then

calling $someObjectOfTypeX->some_static_variable = 'some_value' would change the state of $anotherObjectOfTypeX.

Calling $someObjectOfTypeX->someStaticFunction() however, does not change the state of $anotherObjectOfTypeX.

Although the keyword static is identical it has different implications for functions and variables. Static variables are shared by all instances of a class. Static function don't alter the objects state and therefore also will not change the state of other instances of the same class.

```
<?php

class first
{
    //variable
    public static $var = 5;

    //method
    static function new()
    {
        echo "<br>";
        echo self::$var;
        echo "<br>";
    }
}

$obj1 = new first();
$obj2 = new first();

echo $obj1->var; // this throws an error
echo $obj1::$var; // this runs
echo first::$var; // this runs

$obj2::$var = 10; // changes $var in class first (both object $obj1 and object $obj2)
$obj2->var = 15; // this throws an error (if it didn't it would change the variable also in $obj1)

$obj1->new(); // this also runs
$obj1::new(); // this runs
first::new(); // this runs
```

Comment: You said _Although arbitrary, a static class variable only belongs to a class, not to an object. A static class method belongs to both a class and an object of that class._ But static is a keyword with which we can shared some properties or methods throughout all instances of that class . So that applies to both properties and methods i.e. they both belongs to a class and method. But i was asking here is that why can we access method with both the -> & :: while it can only be accessed with :: in case of property.

Comment: @Sitepose I've extended my answer and explain that the static keyword has different implications for variables and methods.